recitation of Brihadaranyaka Upanishad - chapter 3 section 7
I am looking for the recitation of Brihadaranyaka Upanishad - chapter 3 section 7.
I searched, but couldn't find this section online, although their are many talks related to it - https://archive.org/details/Brihadaranyaka-Upanishad-Antaryami-Brahmanam
It describes Brahman as the inner-controller of everything including:

Earth
Water
Fire
Air
Space
Speech
Eye
Ear
Mind
etc

https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-brihadaranyaka-upanishad/d/doc118358.html
if anyone has any leads for it kindly share.
